# using loop to update value of the variables in haskell

Tags: haskell

I have such a function:

```
elim_one :: Idx -> Idx -> Idx ->  Mat El -> Mat El
elim_one c r1 r2 m = let val1 = ((m!!r1)!!c)
                         val2 = ((m!!r2)!!c)
                         row1 = (mulr r1 val2 m)!!r1
                         row2 = (mulr r2 val1 m)!!r2
                         nrow = zipWith (-) row1 row2
                         matr = if r1 == r2
                                     then m
                                     else replacer r1 nrow m
                      in matr
```

I want to call this function recursively by using the following function type:

```
elim_all :: Idx -> Idx -> Idx -> Idx -> Mat El -> Mat El
```

For this reason, I wrote the following function:

```
elim_all c r1b r1e r2 m = forM_ [(r1b)..(r1e)] $ \i -> do
                              let matr = m
                              let m = elim_one c i r2 matr
                            in m
```

But I get `parse error on input ‘in’` exception. How should I fix for loop?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first issue is an indentation problem. `in` must be indented more.

However, I can't see why you are using `do` and `forM_`, since you are not working in a monadic context. I think this is simply wrong.

If you want to perform multiple nested call to the removal function, either use basic recursion or exploit `foldl'`.

Comment: How can be a basic recursion? Since I am new, I still couldn't fit any recursion to my issue :)

Comment: @yusuf If `r1b==r1e`, you just remove one element. Otherwise (assuming `r1b>r1e`) you remove `r1b` and then you recurse using `r1b+1`.

Comment: @yusuf For instance, this counts from `n` to `m`: `f n m | n==m = [n] | otherwise = n : f (n+1) m` -- the result is the same as `[n..m]` (for `m>=n`). Use the same technique: handle `n` (`r1b`) and "increment" it in the recursive call.

Comment: what is wrong here?                                                                                 elim_all c r1b r1e r2 m
     | r1b == r1e = elim_one c r1b r2 m
     | otherwise = elim_one c r1b r2 m : elim_all c (r1b+1) r1e r2 m

Comment: The last part should probably be `| otherwise = elim_all c (r1b+1) r1e r2 (elim_one c r1b r2 m)`. I used `:` because I was working with lists, you don't need that.